# How To Implement Disabled User Firebase Authentication on Firestore Rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In Firebase We have Firebase Auth & Firestore. I can disable a user by pressing "Disable User" from Firebase Auth. But the problem is, user still able to read,update,delete the document.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function otentikasi(){
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    function checkUid(docId){
      return request.auth.uid == docId;
    }

    function isUserDisabled() {
     //code???
    }
  
    match /backpack/{docId} {
      allow read: if otentikasi() && checkUid(docId) && !isUserDisabled();

      allow update: if otentikasi()
        && checkUid(docId)
        && !isUserDisabled();
        
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to block the user read & update from firestore rules & firebase Auth by modifying this code above? Or there is another better way?**

I know there is a simple way by storing user status in users collection. But I wonder is it possible to just use firebase Auth and firestore rule?

[image: FirestoreDB]

[image: FirebaseAuth]

Comment: Disabled users can't even sign in, so they would not have auth at all in that case.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry, I tag google cloud function because I also suspect there is a way to do it cloud function, the code actually uses google cloud function but inside that code also has try catch. I wonder if adding firestore rule possible, we can just handle the catch() by returning code&message to Front End.

But there is also a code that doesn't need cloud function, like get data and display it to profile such as name, items in backpack etc.

Comment: Security rules and cloud functions are not related in any way.  Any code running in cloud functions using the Admin SDK to query Firestore will always bypass all rules.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
function isUserEnabled() {
   return request.auth != null && !request.auth.token.disabled;
}
```

Comment: `disabled` isn't one of the pre-defined user auth token properties shown in the [documenation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request). The only way this rule would work is if the OP was using custom claims to store per-user information, and they haven't said this is the case.